# SFTP Inbound channel adapter behaviour

Tags: spring, spring-integration

If I create a SFTP inbound channel adapter and send some files using the channel configured as Channel attribute in SFTP. Will the file travel to SFTP remote directory local directory or it will directly flow from channel to local directory

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

First, you don't "send" files with the inbound adapter, you retrieve them.

Second, I don't know what you mean by

> ... directly flow from channel to local directory

The file is copied from the remote directory to the local directory.

The message sent to the channel has a payload of `File` which represents the file in the local directory.

The upcoming 4.2 release (the release candidate is now available) has a `-stream` option on the outbound gateway which allows you to retrieve the remote file as an `InputStream` [see the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway).